# Dynamic key with wildcard in type definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

I'm quite new to Typescript and cannot find if it's possible to have dynamic keys in type definitions.

For example, here is the type that I'm striving for:

```
export interface IQuery {
  locale?: string;
  include?: number;
  limit?: number;
  select?: string;
  skip?: number;
  order?: string;

  // all keys starting with "fields." (e.g. "fields.name[ne]") should be a string
  'fields.*'?: string;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just make that field `Object` type ?

Comment: how about this: `{ fields: { [p: string]: string } }` ? i think nesting it all under `fields` and declaring it to be an object with dynamic keys is the closest you can get

Comment: yeah, i like the object approach, but unfortunately this is for third-party lib and it awaits strings like “fields.name[ne]”

Answer (score 4):

Use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

```js
export interface IQuery {
  // ...
  [key: `fields.${string}`]: string;
}
```